# why does "ionic platform add android" automatically adds permission for android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I cleared up my ionic directory by running `ionic platform rm android` and then added it back with `add` command.

Somehow the `platforms\android\android.json` and `platform\android\AndroidManifest.xml` show unexpectedly

```
        "AndroidManifest.xml": {
            "parents": {
                "/manifest": [
                    {
                        "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS\" />",
                        "count": 1
                    }...
                ]
            }
        }
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Where do these come from?

My `config.xml` only has these:

```
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"/>
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="webContentsDebuggingEnabled" value="true"/>
  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"/>
```

File `package.json` has these plugins listed (does a plugin automatically generate certain permission requirements?)

```
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-vibration",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs",
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git",
      "id": "cordova-plugin-app-version"
    },
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard.git",
      "id": "com.verso.cordova.clipboard"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer"
  ],
```

I am on Windows 10 Pro (altho `ionic info` shows Windows 8.1), using Cordova CLI 6.3.0, Ionic CLI 1.7.16, Node v0.12.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, this has nothing to do with Ionic framework. This permission is added automatically by email composer plugin which you have added in your project. It does that in order to access the configured email account in the device to send email.

Have verified this by adding email composer plugin in my cordova barebone project. It does add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml` you can check it out too by removing this plugin. Hope is helps.

Comment: What if I manually remove this permission? IMHO this should have been an advisory and not concrete injection - I don't want anyone to believe that my app is *capturing* their contacts. btw a +1 for your approach!

Comment: @Dinesh manually removing the permission is not advisable as it may cause problem while trying to use email plugin and also readding  the plugin again brings this permission back to XML file

Comment: no, manual removal has not caused any problem. But I got rid of this plugin and instead added `cordova-plugin-email` which did not add this perm. I believe silently adding new permissions is *wrong* a thing to do.

Comment: @Dinesh ya but depends on the functionality of plugin too. For instance, file plugin too add read write permission for file system as it relies on those permission... Primarily its plugin based... Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Currently (Feb 2017, Cordova 6.5.0) it looks like **cordova-plugin-email** installs **cordova-plugin-email-composer** adding the plugin with **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-email**

If replacing the cordova-plugin-email-composer with the non cordova-plugin-email as described by Dinesh does not work for you you should take also have a look at platforms/android/android.json You probalby find the following:

```
"AndroidManifest.xml": {
                "parents": {
                    "/manifest": [
                        {
                            "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS\" />",
                            "count": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

If you remove this (and rund cordova prepare) you will not find the line in manifest file anymore.

Tested for an app opening the email client with prefilled recipient, subject and body text, gmail opens fine on my Android 4 Device.